# Equivariant splitting of short exact sequences with a $\mathbb {Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-action

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, exact-sequence, equivariant-maps

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and consider a short exact sequence of \emph{free} $\mathbb Z$-modules of finite rank endowed with a $G$-action

$$ 0\to \mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z^m \to \mathbb Z^k\to 0,$$

and suppose that the maps are also $G$-equivariant.
Clearly the sequence splits as sequence of $\mathbb Z$-modules, the question is:

> does the SES  split equivariantly?

Since, using the representation theory of $G$,  any irreducible representation over $\mathbb Z^n$ has rank at most $2$, then I think that we can reduce to the case when $k=2$.

However I expect  this to be well known to algebraists.

Comment: By-the-way, is it true that any representation is a sum of one and two dimensional ones?

Comment: @Galoisgroup yes, see Charles W. Curtis and Irving Reiner. Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras. Theorem 74.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $0 \to \mathbb Z\to  \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\to 0$

Here the action is trivial on the first $\mathbb Z$, permutation of coordinated on the second, and the multiplication on $-1$ on the third. The maps are $f_1(a)=(a,a), f_2(a,b)=a-b$ The reason is that the second $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ is not sum of two $1$-dimensianal representations.